# Apt doesn't get the latest Neovim version

Tags: neovim, installing

I had Neovim v0.4 installed via `apt` (on Ubuntu).
But then I saw there is a [newer version](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/tag/v0.7.0) and tried to install it following instructions [here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim).

Now if I use

```
./nvim.appimage
```

from `~/.config/nvim` folder, the newest version is run, but if I use

```
nvim
```

old version will run.

And if I try to update to newest using `apt-get install neovim`, I'll get

> neovim is already the newest version (0.4.4-1).

Why is this happening and how do I open the latest version directly?

Comment: Try running `hash -r` in your shell, or starting a new one. Then check `which -a nvim`/`command -v nvim`. (Basically: shells cache paths. But this may not be the problem if the installation didn't put links or binaries in the expected places.)

Comment: I managed to get it working by following https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25192/how-to-install-stable-version-of-neovim-on-ubuntu-18-04.

Answer (score 3):

run the following from the folder where you downloaded nvim.appimage

```
sudo cp ./nvim.appimage /usr/local/bin/nvim
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/nvim
```

the reason ubuntu doesn't execute the newest version if you enter nvim is that
nvim.appimage is not in a directory in $PATH.
Whenever you enter a command the shell goes through a list of folders to find the program. If it finds it in a directory it stops searching, which in your case is `/usr/bin/nvim`.
`/usr/local/bin` is also in $PATH, but takes precedence over /usr/bin, so by moving nvim.appimage there you make your shell execute that file instead of the ubuntu provided neovim version.